# Creating links to a page displaying posts from a particular category

Tags: taxonomy, page-template, categories

Ok so at the moment I have a page which displays a list of categories within my Taxonomy (event-themes), here's the code:

```
<div id="themeSearch">
    <h1 class="mainSectionHeader">By Theme</h1>
    <ul id="themeSelector" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <?php
        //list custom portfolio categories
        $taxonomy = 'event-themes';  // define portfolio categories from taxonomies in functions.php
        $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

        foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        echo '<li class="themeItem"><p><span>' . $tax_term->name.'</span></p><a href="index.php?<?php get_the_category( $id ) ?>" rel="' . $tax_term->slug . '"><span>Go</span></a>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

First of all, I am aware that the echo'd link does not work, and that is what I need help with.

I'm trying to not only display all of the categories, but I also want each of them to **link to a page displaying the posts within that particular category**.

I think I'm almost there with this code, as what I am trying to do is **insert the category ID within the href so that for each listed category it directs to the correct page**.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($tax_term).'">'.$tax_term->name.'</a>';
}
```

Simplified a bit from your version for readability.